# Scrolling down in popup window not working as intended

Tags: vimscript, popup-menu

I have the following code:

```
let text = range(50)->map({_,i -> string(i)})
let winid = popup_create(text, {
    \ 'line': 1,
    \ 'col': 1,
    \ 'minwidth': 1,
    \ 'minheight': 1,
    \ 'cursorline': 1,
    \ 'wrap': 0,
    \ 'mapping': 0,
    \ 'filter': 'popup_filter_menu',
    \ 'firstline': 1,
    \ })
```

Which create a popup window on the side of the screen (left side depending on how you place yourself) and list a range of numbers, between 1 to 50.

The scrolling however, does not continue after the number 34 (where it is supposed to scroll down to 35, etc)

Any ways to make the scrolling work as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to limit the height of the popup, at least 1 line less than the height of the terminal window, by including this key in the options dictionary passed to [popup_create()](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup_create()):

```
maxheight: &lines - 1
```

For example:

```
call range(50)
    \ ->map({_, i -> string(i)})
    \ ->popup_create(#{
    \     line: 1,
    \     col: 1,
    \     minwidth: 1,
    \     minheight: 1,
    \     maxheight: &lines - 1,
    \     cursorline: 1,
    \     wrap: 0,
    \     mapping: 0,
    \     filter: 'popup_filter_menu',
    \     firstline: 1,
    \     })
```

Comment: This works great! seems it also fix a problem i had when scrolling up too :D. Cheers.